# User side metadata reveals for ERC-721 tokens

Tags: erc-721, nft, meta-data

I'm helping a friend create a project where the project slowly mints and reveals over time. What's the best way to ensure no metadata is leaked? Here's how it'll work

user mints a NFT, user calls a reveal function, nft is revealed.

however, if we set the baseurl prior to this, won't the community be able to secure metadata information before the actual token is minted? eg if the base URL is set at xxx/1.json for the first unit, and I've uploaded all the files, wouldn't users be able to check xxx/2.json for the unminted NFT's expected metadata? I'm not certain how safe metadata generation can be done here.

Cheers